# How long should I sear meat after thawing from frozen state?

Tags: reheating

I generally sous vide more food than I can eat at one time, so I put the extra food in a water bath and then freeze.  I'm wondering how long and at what temperature I need to sear meats after thawing to make sure they are hot but not overcooked.  I generally sear on the grill but sometimes in a skillet. Thanks!!!

Comment: Aren't you kind of losing the benefits of sous vide this way? If you sear it long enough to fully heat up, you're going to overcook the outside as badly as if you'd never used sous vide in the first place. Are you sure you don't want to reheat with the sous vide instead, and then optionally sear for texture?

Comment: I suppose it depends on why one is using a sous vide.  We mainly use it in order to precook a lot of meat for easy and quick reheating without sacrificing moisture and tenderness. Tonight I couldn't find the answer to my question so I just ended up doing what I thought was best.  I turned the grill up to high and seared  the meat for about 2 minutes on each side.  It worked great!

Answer (score 1):

The Sous Vide Supreme website recommends reheating in the water bath for 45 minutes per inch of thickness (adding 30 minutes if reheating from frozen).  I would do this at a temperature equal to, or a degree or two lower than, your initial cook so as not to over cook.  Then sear or grill as normal...a minute or so per side.